# Bash Script : Passing array as an argument to a function and printing the array

Tags: bash

I am passing an array to a function and trying to print each and every element of the array.

Below is the code snippet with quotes around the array parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

print_array ()
{
        array=$@
        for i in "${array[@]}" #with quotes
        do
                echo $i
        done
}

ar=("1. a" "2. b" "3. c")
print_array ${ar[@]}
```

When I execute the above script, the output is

```
1. a 2. b 3. c
```

Below is the code snippet without quotes around the array parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash

print_array ()
{
        array=$@
        for i in ${array[@]} #without quotes
        do
                echo $i
        done
}

ar=("1. a" "2. b" "3. c")
print_array ${ar[@]}
```

When I execute the above script, the output is

```
1.
a
2.
b
3.
c
```

The output varies according to the quotes around the array parameter.
I am really confused with the output displayed. Please help me out to resolve it.

The expected output should be :

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
```

Comment: You can't copy an array into a scalar -- a scalar can hold a single array element only, but not more than that without losing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

print_array ()
{
        for i;
        do
                printf "%s\n" "$i"
        done
}

ar=("1. a" "2. b" "3. c")
print_array "${ar[@]}"  # with quotes
```

If you want to be explict, you can write `for i in "$@"`

You can also write:

```
#!/bin/bash

print_array ()
{
        array=("$@")
        for i in "${array[@]}"; do
                printf "%s\n" "$i"
        done
}

ar=("1. a" "2. b" "3. c")
print_array "${ar[@]}"  # with quotes
```

Comment: it does not work, if I want store the argument in the function and then print the array.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?  You give desired output in the question, and this produces the desired output.

Comment: I want to pass the array argument to a function, store the argument in the function in a variable and then want to print each element of the array.

Comment: Which is precisely what this does.  The array is stored in the builtin array indexed by the positional parameters.  If you want to copy it to another array (although there is no need to do so), use the second version.

Comment: The only adjustment I'd suggest making here is `echo "$i"`, or `printf '%s\n' "$i"` if we want to be robust against arguments such as `-E` or `-n`.

Comment: @Willam Pursell, thanks so much. Could you please do the below two things.
1. Please change ar => array in function print_arrary. Becoz of this I said it wont work.
2. Could you explain, why this weird output with or without quotes.

Comment: There's no weird output.  Although you name the variable "array", it is not an array.  The RHS is a string, so the variable you have named "array" is a string.  By putting the RHS inside parens, I make it an array.

Comment: IOW, `$@` is a string, `("$@")` is an array.  `($@)` is also an array, but with a different number of elements.

Comment: @sach, using the same name `array` both inside and outside the function would actually be a bad idea, since by default (without an explicit `local` declaration), variables inside function definitions are actually global in scope.

Comment: @sach, ...so, by using `ar` inside and `array` outside, this question demonstrates that the values are successfully passed through `$@`, and avoids any pitfalls related to reuse of names. (Running `local -a array` inside the function would be another, better way to avoid that).

Comment: @WilliamPursell, why are the quotes so mandatory to get the desired output.

Comment: @sach, if you don't quote you get string-splitting and glob-expansion, so individual words inside the string (as distinguished by splitting on characters in IFS) are passed as individual arguments. For extra fun, try passing the literal asterisk character surrounded by one of your spaces within an array element, and you'll see what glob expansion does when you don't quote also.

Comment: @sach, ...in particular, unquoted `${array[@]}` behaves precisely the same way as unquoted `${array[*]}` -- it combines each array element by the first character of `IFS`, and then splits them out again.

Comment: William Pursell and Charles Duffy, thanks a lot for the clarification.
Would you suggest the book which you refer for bash scripting.

Comment: @sach, I don't strongly recommend any dead-tree reference, but the documentation at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide (also the FAQ, the pitfalls page, etc) is a good choice (actively maintained by folks who care deeply about correctness and showcasing good practices).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

print_array ()
{
    array=("$@")
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
            echo "$i"
    done
}

ar=("1. a" "2. b" "3. c")
print_array "${ar[@]}"
```

Result:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
```

Using  =()  during assignment keeps the variable as an array.